# Deep learning model to clean documents

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to build a Convolutional Autoencoder which can remove pen marks such as circles, underlines, etc from official documents.

I have the original, clean soft copy of the document and the xeroxed copy with the pen marks.

The xeroxed copy would obviously not completely match up with the original doc and it would be slightly skewed or shifted, etc while scanning.

Additionally, since the doc size is huge (2360, 1650), I had to split the image into 4 halves of size (587, 412) to input into my model.

What I would like to know is would the above issues cause any problems while training and is there any way to rectify it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

[image: Original Image]

[image: Noisy Image]

As you can see (hopefully!!), the noisy image is slightly different because of skewness or translation while xeroxing.

Comment: I didn't understand clearly what your problem is? You can split or resize your train data with no problem but whatever you do with them you have to do with the test data too.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it will cause any problems. But, if it does, you can always load the image, resize it to a desired shape and then input it into the model.

Comment: Hi...the resizing is not the problem...the problem is that my noisy image data is xeroxed and scanned copies with handwritten underlines, circles, etc. While xeroxing...the pages are distorted and skewed, which means a particular (587, 412) cut of image will not match completely (content-wise) with the original image....because of this while training I am not seeing any reduction in loss